# Get element CSS3 background-color gradient with JS

Tags: jquery, css, background, find, gradient

At the moment I use the following JS (jQuery) to find the background color (as rgb) of several other divs:

```
$theColor = $(this).css("background-color");
```

It works perfectly, except with CSS3 gradients.

As an example, I have the following css to make the background of a div look similar to a post-it note:

```
background: #FFFAAD; /* old browsers */

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFAAD 0%, #FFF47D 100%); /* firefox */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FFFAAD), color-stop(100%,#FFF47D)); /* webkit */

background: gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FFFAAD), color-stop(100%,#FFF47D));

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFAAD', endColorstr='#FFF47D',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
```

jQuery doesn't seem to pick up anything.

How can I use jQuery to find at least one of the colors used in a css3 gradient?
I am relatively new to JS, so please bear with me..

Thank you.

Comment: The gradient isn't a colour, it's a background image.  Checking the `background-color` isn't going to tell you anything about the background image.

Comment: There is no background image set; this is purely css3. I doubt these gradients are stored as images (or are even possible to store as images).

Comment: There is a background image, the gradient is the background image.  That's why your CSS says `background: -moz-linear-gradient` instead of `background-color: -moz-linear-gradient`

Comment: [Here's the CSS spec that covers gradients](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#gradients), have a look at what it's called

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create an cssHook for *gradient* (jQuery has for example an hook implemented for *opacity*).

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/

As requested an example-code for retrieving the colors:

```
(function($){   

    if ( !$.cssHooks ){
        //if not, output an error message
        alert("jQuery 1.4.3 or above is required for this plugin to work");
        return;
    }
    div = document.createElement( "div" ),
    css = "background-image:gradient(linear,left top,right bottom, from(#9f9), to(white));background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#9f9),to(white));background-image:-moz-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#9f9),to(white));background-image:-o-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#9f9),to(white));background-image:-ms-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#9f9),to(white));background-image:-khtml-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#9f9),to(white));background-image:linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);background-image:-khtml-linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);";    
    div.style.cssText = css;


    $.support.linearGradient =
    div.style.backgroundImage.indexOf( "-moz-linear-gradient" )  > -1 ? '-moz-linear-gradient' :
    (div.style.backgroundImage.indexOf( "-webkit-gradient" )  > -1 ? '-webkit-gradient' :
    (div.style.backgroundImage.indexOf( "linear-gradient" )  > -1 ? 'linear-gradient' : false));
    if ( $.support.linearGradient)
    {
      $.cssHooks['linearGradientColors'] = { 
        get: function(elem){
          var currentStyle=$.css(elem, 'backgroundImage'),gradient,colors=[];
          gradient=currentStyle.match(/gradient(\(.*\))/g);
          if(gradient.length)
          {
            gradient=gradient[0].replace(/(linear|radial|from|\bto\b|gradient|top|left|bottom|right|\d*%)/g,'');
            colors= jQuery.grep(gradient.match(/(rgb\([^\)]+\)|#[a-z\d]*|[a-z]*)/g),function (s) { return jQuery.trim( s )!=''})
          }
          return colors;
        }
    };
 }
})(jQuery);
```

As I said it's just an example how to work with cssHooks, not meant for production usage. Works for me in ff, chrome, IE9, safari.
A set-function can be found if you follow the link posted by RickV.

Usage: `$('selector').css('linearGradientColors')`
Return: an array with the colors

Comment: Don't you still have to write some JavaScript to return the value in the `get` of the hook?

Comment: Yes, of course. If you need something that isn't implemented in jQuery yet, you'll have to write it on your own, and gradient isn't implemented.

Comment: The question here is what do you need to write to implement it in jQuery.

Comment: The question was "How can I use jQuery" and my answer is "cssHooks", because that's the way how to use jQuery here.

Comment: The question is: "Get element CSS3 background-color gradient with JS."

Comment: Read the question - not only the headline, and also see the tags.

Comment: OK, this is from the question: "How can I use jQuery to find at least one of the colors used in a css3 gradient?"

Comment: Cool, I updated [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/KHrrB/9/) to use your `cssHook`.  I had to make one change, `if(gradient.length)` to `if(gradient && gradient.length)` otherwise I got an error on elements without a gradient.  Also note it does weird things in Opera because that browser preserves the `#rrggbb` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the fixes:) I guess I need to update my opera sometimes, my version doesn't support gradients^^

Answer (score 2):

Like pointed, use [CSS Hooks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/) to do it.

You will find a sample with your need here: http://www.webmuse.co.uk/articles/csshooks-in-jquery/.

Comment: That's a nice link, but at the bit where it might solve the problem the question is asking it says this: `'get' not really needed as we only want to be able to override setting a style, not really getting`

Comment: Where the OP said it? Their question is about getting the value.

Answer (score -1):

You can extract the colours used in the gradient by looking at the `background-image` property of the element and then extracting the listed colours.  [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/KHrrB/), it's using the [CSS colour matching RegEx from this post](http://www.kylirhorton.com/2008/a-regular-expression-that-matches-css-colors/).  I've just bound the code to the `onclick` event of the elements with the background:

```
$("div").bind("click", function() {
    window.alert('Background color: ' + ($(this).css('background-color')));
    var re = /(#([0-9A-Fa-f]{3,6})\b)|(aqua)|(black)|(blue)|(fuchsia)|(gray)|(green)|(lime)|(maroon)|(navy)|(olive)|(orange)|(purple)|(red)|(silver)|(teal)|(white)|(yellow)|(rgb\(\s*\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b\s*,\s*\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b\s*,\s*\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b\s*\))|(rgb\(\s*(\d?\d%|100%)+\s*,\s*(\d?\d%|100%)+\s*,\s*(\d?\d%|100%)+\s*\))/g;
    var colors = ($(this).css('background-image')).match(re);
    for (var i=0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        window.alert('Gradient colour: ' + colors[i]);
    }
});
```

Note that the RegEx is for CSS2 colours, so it won't match any `rgba()` or `hsla()` colours but it ought to be possible for you to extend it if necessary.

Comment: What's the jQuery-part here (as requested by the OP)?  Retrieving the current style? Also if you ignore it, cssHooks is the method to work with here instead of this solution.

Comment: @DrMolle `$(this).css('background-color')` would be the relevant jQuery.  There's no need to do anything with `cssHooks` because the information required is already available in standard jQuery.

Comment: Really, and if somebody ask's for an alert-box with jquery you suggest `$(window)[0].alert('an alert with jquery');` . I'm pretty sure that in the end he not only needs to know some color. cssHooks let him extend jquery to his own needs without losing the  known usabilty.

Comment: @DrMolle Sorry, I should have said `$(this).css('background-image')` in my previous comment, because the issue is that `$(this).css('background-color')` isn't returning the information he wants.  How would I use `cssHooks` in this situation?  What benefit would it give over returning the information with `$(this).css('background-image')`?  Please update your answer with the code if putting it in a comment is too limiting.

Comment: The benefit is simple, I can use it the jQuery-way for getting css-values instead of defining somewhere any functions that break the usual jQuery-workflow. I've updated my post with an example.