# CSS3 Jquery Gradients - is there any way to read the values set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, linear-gradients

Lets say I have the following CSS:

```
._gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #6AF 16px, #0032C8 24px);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6AF 16px, #0032C8 24px);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6AF 16px, #0032C8 24px);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6AF 16px, #0032C8 24px);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6AF 16px, #0032C8 24px);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(16px, #6AF),color-stop(24px, #0032C8));
}
```

Is there any way **simple** with Javascript or jQuery to read the values for the gradient position / direction / color?

obviously I could using Regular Expressions... the problem would lie in  'background-image' value returning a different value dependent on which browser was accessing the site: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/willisilliw/skcf4/)

Basically now this led me to try just with the `linear-gradient()` value (aiming to do browser detect and apply the CSS with jQuery) but this returned the value 'none': [jsFiddle example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/willisilliw/skcf4/2/)

Bare in mind my actual aim is to get these values dynamically with the script, not set them (although I'm willing for the solution to require me to do this).

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**
I am looking for a way to read the values in a gradient, even if gradients are not supported. using `$.cssHooks` is not the answer due to the fact that if the property is nou supported, it returns the value 'none' which has no benefit what so ever.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929707/get-element-css3-background-color-gradient-with-js

Comment: Doesn't work due to issue in example 2, like I said, I am trying to get the `color` , `position` and `direction`. If the data is available to `cssHooks`, it will also be returned by `$(elem).css('background-image')` however you can't 'get' unsupported CSS values and the having to `regex` for the different types of gradient supported in different browsers seems a little extreme.

Comment: i guess that's not possible without using regexp, and YES, you will have to check if the value is 'none', jump to the next possible type.. here a possible work-around that may work:

`<div class="_gradient" linear-gradient="blah|blah"></div>​`

then read the attr from the element

$('._gradient').html($('._gradient').attr('linear-gradient'));​

or even better use an attribute for every value you need, top, rgba, etc..
i hope that helps !

Comment: it'd have to be data-linear-gradient="" to be HTML5 compliant but I was thinking along the same lines, then using jQuery to apply the gradient and PHP to generate the image file if no gradient was supported... Can't wait for the plain `linear-gradient` to be supported (in 50 years time...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this roughly do what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/2wQed/2/

Comment: Unfortunately no, if an unsupported value is present it displays the name of the background image but ideally I need the position, color and direction values.

Comment: Ah ok. I know you don't want to do it that way but I can't see a simpler way without regex'ing the value in that case unfortunately...

Comment: Problem there is that in browsers that support no type of CSS gradient, it returns the value 'none' ... I think a solution might be to name the gradient file something like FFFFFF_10_CCCCCC_40_FF0000_100 but that's a complete nightmare to contemplate!

Comment: although not the correct answer, this is the closest anybody got to a correct answer and the actual answer to the question is "you can't do it"

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/

found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929707/get-element-css3-background-color-gradient-with-js), not sure if it works, but maybe it worths tryin

Comment: That was already suggested in the comments and again, it doesn't work for what I am trying to do.